# NSManagedObjects that have been inserted but not yet saved?

Tags: ios, core-data, ios8, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Is is possible to identify (at runtime) `NSManagedObjects` that have been inserted into a `NSManagedObjectContext` (i.e. `inserted == YES`) but have never been [`save`d](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/save:) to the context's store so far.

I first thought their `objectID` may still be `nil` but this turned out not to be the case.

**UPDATE** I have conducted a quick experiment to see if checking `temporaryID` (see [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28011911/1789384)) also works for nested MOCs. This suggests no: saving the child MOC pushes only one level up (i.e. to parent MOC but not to persistent store, which is further up), hence the object ID for a newly inserted MO remains temporary. One way to determine whether a MO is new in the child MOC and has never been saved (not even to the parent MOC) in this case is apparently checking for `[child objectRegisteredForID: object.objectID] && ![parent objectRegisteredForID: object.objectID]` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `temporaryID` [property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectID_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSManagedObjectID/temporaryID) of `NSManagedObjectID`:

> YES if the receiver is temporary, otherwise NO. Most object IDs return
>   NO. New objects inserted into a managed object context are assigned a
>   temporary ID which is replaced with a permanent one once the object
>   gets saved to a persistent store.

Example usage:

```
if(object.objectID.isTemporaryID) {
  //the object has not been saved yet
}
```

Comment: Do you know if the scheme can scale to nested managed object contexts (MOC) as well. For instance, I assume that if I save a child MOC for the first time its MOs will still have temporary IDs because save is pushed only one level up (hence to the parent MOC, not the persistent store)? Is there still a way for finding those of the child MOC's MOs that have never been saved (not even to the parent MOC)? Perhaps via `insertedObjects`? If you prefer, I can post a separate question.

Comment: Will experiment and then perhaps do. I just read elsewhere that "to the child MOC the parent MOC is the persistent store". So maybe it's really as simple as using the same strategy also for nested MOCs.

Comment: Have done the experiment (and updated the question).